# How to open sliding drawer from outside button not with its child handle button?

Tags: android, slider, slidingmenu

I like to open sliding drawer from any out side button not with its child button handle , If any one have any answer or tutorial please help me?

I want to open a slider from any other button in layout not from handle button ... not from its child button ??

like if I have any button in xml.. and when I click on it slider open .

[Android Sliding Up View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21849032/android-sliding-up-view)
 please check it and see the screen shot I don't have that much reputation so that I upload Image

I want to click on show button the slider opens not on slider

Comment: `open sliding drawer from any out side button` means what?

Comment: Could you please give us more details? I don't even fully understand what you are asking...

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to open a slider from any other button in layout not from handle button ...

Comment: @user3332166, Any other button means any custom button or imageview you specify, is this what you are asking?

Answer (score 0):

The "Navigation Drawer" can be opened programmatically with `mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerContentLayout)`. Here's some info how to set it up:

```
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private RelativeLayout mDrawerContentLayout;
```

Get the reference to drawerView in your Activity `onCreate()`:

```
mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
mDrawerContentLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_content);
```

Call this on your button click when you want drawer opened:

```
mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerContentLayout);
```

I used a `RelativeLayout` as content view of my drawer, but you can use any which suits you. Just remember, the `mDrawerLayout` layout should be inside `mDrawerLayout` (which is actually a `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`) and should have the `android:layout_gravity="start"` attribute.

Here's the (abbreviated) activity layout that I used:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
      android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="top"
      android:background="#33b5e5"
      android:paddingBottom="4dp"
      android:paddingTop="4dp"
      android:textColor="#fff" />
  </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_content"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" >

    <ListView
      ... />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

You can find more details in the [API documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html#openDrawer%28android.view.View%29), the [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) and the [design patterns](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if you want to open slider on it's button's click then use below code.

```
sliding_menu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.slidingMenu);
        sliding_menu.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                menu.showMenu();
            }
        });
```

Comment: same u r telling above

Comment: Not for this code, but generally like you have used any library or you are using code from android developer site etc...

Comment: Which library you used like jfeinstein or some else