# iOS sliding panel from bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Im searching sliding panel from the bottom like the control center from ios? 
But with a little height.
Basically is a typical reveal panel but not from the typical right/left edges.
Anything like this for android:  https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: what work have you done searching for how to do such a thing? what have you tried?

Comment: maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're asking for, but just add a view to your view controller with y=screen.height, then animate to where ever you want the new y to be.

Comment: I searched on cocoacontrols.com and also in google

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21849032/android-sliding-up-view  or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21849032/android-sliding-up-view or whatever panel you find that appears from the left/right