# Slide in view from bottom over Google Map on Marker click

Tags: android, google-maps, floating-action-button

I want to achieve the following:
[GMaps slide in mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug0Cf.png)

The Info view should slide in from the bottom when I click on a marker. The black circle is a Floating Action Button and should rise to the top with the info window and rest with its center at the upper border of the info window.

When I click anywhere but on the info window, it should slide back down and disappear.

Could you give me some starting points? I already read about object animators and the CoordinatorLayout, yet I don't know where to begin.

Comment: Again? Please... Google it: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel this has been answer many, many times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21849032/android-sliding-up-view and many others.

Answer (score 8):

You can implement it yourself by adding a **bottomsheet** element to the parent layout of the `MapFragment` and then setting a custom `OnMarkerClickListener`.

For the bottom sheet to work, you should use the `CoordinatorLayout` for the parent of the `MapFragment`. To create a bottomsheet element, you should set `app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior`to a layout element, such as a `NestedScrollView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="550dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white" android:clipToPadding="true"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">


    <TextView android:id="@+id/detail_name" android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="25dp"
        android:layout_weight="3" android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge" />

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

The map fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

  <fragment
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your activity class, you can set up the bottom sheet initial behaviour in `onCreate()`:

```
private BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior;
private View bottomSheet;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
    bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(200);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);
    bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
    }
```

Then modify the map behaviour in `onMapReady()`:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            updateBottomSheetContent(marker);
            return true;
        }
    });
    map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
        }
    });
}

private void updateBottomSheetContent(Marker marker) {
    TextView name = (TextView) bottomSheet.findViewById(R.id.detail_name);
    name.setText(marker.getTitle());
  bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
}
```

Of course, you can also use some data stored in the marker to query your database or `ContentProvider` for appropriate record and then use the returned data to set more text, images, etc. in the bottom sheet.

Answer (score 2):

The Flipboard bottom sheet will do it, but without the FAB.
[Flipboard/bottomsheet](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet)

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. Although I find it weird that everyone is using a third party library for such a basic thing. Seems to be way more complicated than I thought.

Comment: You may try to use this implementation, without third part libraries, although I haven't tested yet: [framelayout-your-best-ui-friend](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/10/framelayout-your-best-ui-friend/)