# Android creating a custom onMarkerClickListener

Tags: android, onclick, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to implement the android `OnMarkerClickListener` on a custom class which shall be used as the click listener whenever a marker is clicked.

This is how I'm implementing it:

First I create a custom class that implements `GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener` like so:

```
    public class CustomMarkerClick extends MapsActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    private String mHaoTitle, mHaoDescription;
    private Context context;


    public CustomMarkerClick(Context context, String haoTitle, String haoDescription) {
        this.context = context;
        this.mHaoTitle = haoTitle;
        this.mHaoDescription = haoDescription;

        //I used this to check whether the values are being supplied to the constructor successfully
        Toast.makeText(context, haoTitle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        LinearLayout bottomSheetViewgroup = (LinearLayout) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet_hao);
        bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheetViewgroup);
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED );

        TextView tv = (TextView) ((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.txt_hao_title);
        tv.setText(mHaoTitle);
        return false;
    }
}
```

And this is when a marker is clicked:

```
 mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new CustomMarkerClick(MapsActivity.this, bsHaoName, haoRetriever.getDescription()));
```

The problem is that whenever I try to `setText` on a `TextView` in the `onMarkerClick` method, the text is not actually *visible*. For example the haoTitle string that is supplied through the constructor is not visible inside the `onMarkerCLick` method

Comment: did you try `infoWindowAdapter `?

Answer (score 1):

I used `infoWindowAdapter` in my code. Which is as following ..

```
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                View v = mapActivity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                        R.layout.info_window_layout, null);

                ((TextView) v).setText(marker.getTitle());
                return v;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                // Getting view from the layout file info_window_layout View

                // Getting reference to the TextView to set title TextView

                // Returning the view containing InfoWindow contents return
                return null;

            }

        });

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                marker.showInfoWindow();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Let me try this and will get back to you in a few

Comment: I dont think this will fit the user requirement, it has to be a bottom sheet that displays the information, can the info dialog be modified to mimic the looks of a bottom sheet?

Comment: then you might have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38054374/6155248) , if still no help, please let me know