# How to do pull up animation (as in Google Maps)

Tags: android, android-animation

Does anyone have an idea of how the Google Maps app implements the pull up animation of the card that appears when you select a place?

I wanted to know what would be the best structure to achieve it (as it looks a bit complex). How to divide in components (activities, fragment, views) and what is the general idea of it.

You can see the example of the animation below:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jgyaesga2u3jlzc/maps.mp4?dl=0

Comment: A bit old, but take a look at this blog - http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/10/framelayout-your-best-ui-friend/

Comment: Or a github repo - https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Comment: This is also a duplicate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826892/replicate-google-maps-bottom-panel-swipe-up